# Go - Duplicate case in switch statement

Tags: go

I am new to `Go`, and while attempting to remove some duplicate code across switch statements I added a case with `fallthrough` like so:

```
i := 1
switch i {
case 0, 1:
    fmt.Println("common code")
    fallthrough
case 0:
    fmt.Println("aux for 0")
case 1:
    fmt.Println("aux for 1")
default:
    fmt.Println("other number")

}
```

However, I received an error about the duplicate cases such as:

```
prog.go:13: duplicate case 0 in switch
    previous case at prog.go:10
prog.go:15: duplicate case 1 in switch
    previous case at prog.go:10
```

Why is this an error? Is there some way to instruct the compiler to allow such code?

Comment: Even if the duplicate case wasn't an error, this code wouldn't do what you expect -- after the `fallthrough`, you'd enter the `case 0` block, even if `i` was `1`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Somehow I got the impression that, unlike C, it would check the case condition on `fallthrough`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behavior, in the current Go, is that the `switch` is implemented like an `if-else-if`.  Obviously, `if (1) else if (1)` doesn't make sense, thus you get this error.

Right now, there is no way to force the compiler to do this.  You have to rewrite your statements to get the effect you want.

Per [this bug report comment supposedly quoting Rob Pike](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4524#c7), this restriction will be lifted in a future Go version.

Comment: I don't see evidence for "will be lifted" there. I see a discussion with no clear resolution (at best, "leaning toward" a resolution). Also note that even if the restriction were lifted, switch would still only execute the first matching case, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one case statement for each value, so that code is illegal. Additionally, fallthrough only works once, so even if it worked as you wanted for 0, it would still fail for 1.

The simplest solution is to put the initial 0,1 case in its own switch or if before the main switch.